# Why Eclipse m2e plugin deploy wrong formatted jars to Tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am using Eclipse m2e plugin to import existing web app to Eclipse. And Tomcat is used to deploy the web app. I run the Tomcat from Eclipse' Servers list.
And everything works fine except when I got ClassNotFoundException when I tried to Run the project on Tomcat Server. The not found class is a class from another m2e project which is depended by the web app project.

And I navigated into the web app deployment folder like 

`$EclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib`

 and found out the jar containing complained not found class was indeed generated in WEB-INF/lib. But the jar was in weird layout.

The layout was like below 
   `src/main/java/com/mycompany/xxx.java 
   target/classes/com/mycompany/xxx.class`

but not expected
   `com/mycompany/xxx.class`

I looked into the Deployment Assembly section of the web app properties, everything was fine.

Why the Eclipse(or the m2e plugin) generates wrong formatted JAR files?

Comment: how does your folder structure look like and your pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise, my projects are organized as typical multi-projects structure. At the root, a parent pom (packaged as pom) is defined, and the subfolders are organized as children projects of the parent pom. From the parent as root, we have son-level projects and grandson-projects. There are so many projects, I can only summarize like this.

Comment: What exactly is your problem, cause what you have described looks ok so far..

Comment: @khmarbaise As I described, it is not working well, the JARs generated following the Deployment Assembly instruction contains weird target/ folders.

Comment: Have you tried to run your build on console? Via `mvn clean package` from the root pom of your project...

Comment: Yes, all mvn commands are OK, such as mvn clean/package/install/test.

Answer (score 1):

I was using maven Eclipse plugin to generate .classpath, .project files and .settings/ folder for Eclipse, via 
`mvn eclipse:eclipse`
.

I didn't clean all these Eclipse 
`.classpath file
.project file
.wtpmodules file 
.setting folder`
 
before I used Eclipse m2e plugin.

At the end I deleted all these 

`.classpath file
.project file
.wtpmodules file 
.setting folder`
.
And re-import all the maven projects to Eclipse using m2e plugin.

Then the issue I mentioned was gone! All jars are now in good shape!
Looks like the existing Eclipse files causes the m2e plugin not happy, and generated unexpected result.

Comment: Dont use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` cause [maven-eclipse-plugin is retired](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) Use M2E instead.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, that's the reason why I am migrating to M2E.

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason to migrate to m2e cause you remove all the eclipse specific files from your project (.project, .classpath, .settings) and import the whole project as maven project...This should work if not your pom is the cause...

Comment: @khmarbaise What I observed is that if I removed all the eclipse stuff generated by mvn eclipse:eclipse, then m2e works perfectly. But I I didn't remove them, I observed m2e ran into a very strange state, such as generating jars with target/ folder. I don't know the reason, since the plugin itself is quite complicated.